# Upload файла на ajax + php

Tags: ajax, fileupload, post, php

**upd**: Вообщем я сделал по примеру, и всё нормально.

Как мне можно сделать, чтобы после загрузки файла, ссылка на файл и еще какая нибудь информация типа размера отправлялась в сообщении, без обновления страницы ?

upd: спасибо вам на этом :)

Comment: Обычным способо вы файл не отправите ajax-запросом. Тут есть некоторые тонкости. Или используйте готовые плагины для загрузки файлов, или , если хотите своими силами, то [почитайте тут][1], думаю, что прояснит ситуацию.

   [1]:http://incode.pro/jquery/ajax-na-praktike-zagruzka-fajlov.html

Comment: @Deonis благодарю

Comment: Скромно напомню что для того чтобы отправлять файлы с помощью AJAX, используется FormData, которая не поддерживается ie8,9,Opera Preso если поддержка этих браузеров для Вас актуальна лучше делать отправку файлов "с перезагрузкой"

Comment: @Олег Б скомно напомню, что для не поддерживаемых браузеров используется fallback в передачу через iframe. там и параметры формы можно отправлять.

Comment: @Deonis можно ли отправлять эти данные без json ?

@Олег Б это не важно, всё делается для себя

Comment: > можно ли отправлять эти данные без json ?

@Евгений  Кузнецов, если вы о **dataType: 'json'**, то этот параметр отвечает за то, в каком формате ожидается ответ сервера, а не отправку.

Comment: @Deonis ясно, по вопросу не подскажите ?

Comment: @Евгений  Кузнецов, а что ж вам тут подсказать? Для получения информации о фалйе, есть [много функций][1], а ссылка формируется из того пути, куда вы загружаете файл + его новое или старое имя.

   [1]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/book.filesystem.php